# Add lines to xmlfile after certain text batch

Tags: xml, batch-file

I am trying to add two lines to .csproj documents (xml) through batch. Because there are so many of them, having this automated is something really important.

Each file contains the following line (twice, needs to be added both times):

```
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
```

after which the following lines need to be added:

```
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\..\Ruleset\Ruleset\RuleSet1.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
```

How can I get this done with a batch file?

Summary:

1. Loop through all files in a directory for .csproj files
2. Search for line containing text
3. Add text in next lines

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.csproj"') DO (
 REM the following line deletes the "...new" file
 DEL "%sourcedir%\%%~na.new" 2>nul
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%sourcedir%\%%a") DO (
  >>"%sourcedir%\%%~na.new" ECHO(%%b
  ECHO("%%b"|FIND "<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>" >nul
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  >>"%sourcedir%\%%~na.new" ECHO(^<CodeAnalysisRuleSet^>..\..\Ruleset\Ruleset\RuleSet1.ruleset^</CodeAnalysisRuleSet^>
  >>"%sourcedir%\%%~na.new" ECHO(^<RunCodeAnalysis^>true^</RunCodeAnalysis^>
  )
 )
 REM use the following line to compare the files
 FC "%sourcedir%\%%~na.new" "%sourcedir%\%%a"
 REM AFTER VERIFICATION, Remove the ECHO from the following line to rename the results
 ECHO MOVE /y "%sourcedir%\%%~na.new" "%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should fulfill that task. All you'd need to do is set up the source directory - I used my current directory for testing.